# How to select multiple places (sublime) in code in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, shortcut, jetbrains-ide

How to select multiple places in code in Android Studio ?

I want to insert the same text in multiple places in my source code. Like a have more than one mouse cursor. I used to do it in VS2012 so easily though not sure how to do it in Android Studio ?

Answer (score 309, accepted):

I found how and lets share this cool feature with you. I found three cool features:

1. For multiple selection just hold <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> then select whenever you want to change by mouse click then type some thing you can write at multiple places at the same time.
2. Another cool feature is column selection. This lets you to click in a great manner and greatly of help especially when you are refactoring.

In most systems it works with holding `middleMouseButton` and dragging over your code and in others it works by holding <kbd>alt</kbd> and selecting code it acts like below:

[image: It selects like this]

3. the third cool feature is sublime selection it finds the same word in code and let you change that or append that easily. you can do that by pressing <kbd>alt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> on **Windows / Linux** and <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> on **mac**. Look how it works:

[image: its great for refactoring]

Also as @Narayana said in comments, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd> selects all occurrences in one shot, for one-shot refactoring on **windows**. to do this on **mac** use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>G</kbd>.

Comment: Cool indeed! Thanks. Also discovered, `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `Alt` + `j` **selects all** occurrences in one shot, for one-shot refactoring.

Comment: tnx . ill add it to my answer

Comment: How undo this option in Mac

Comment: Esc ought to do it.

Comment: @NarayanaJ You can use `SHIFT` + `F6` to refactor rename almost anything and everything in Android Studio.

Doing so will refactor it in other files too.

Comment: `Control` + `Command` + `G` for Mac.

Comment: nice, that selects all occurrences at once instead of having to click ctrl+g multiple times.

Answer (score 36):

You can use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click multiple locations to for multiple cursor.

To select similar occurrences in files use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>j</kbd>.

For more details : [Click Here](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2014/03/intellij-idea-13-1-rc-introduces-sublime-text-style-multiple-selections/)

Answer (score 32):

#### Multiline Caret (without mouse)

Windows: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>

Mac: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>⌘</kbd>(Hold) + <kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>

<kbd>ESC</kbd> will end multiline mode.

#### Change Multi-caret Hotkey

To add a custom Keymap, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, type `keymap` and click on the one with `Settings` as subtext. Search for `Clone Caret Above` and `Clone Caret Below`.

I mapped mine to <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>↑ / ↓</kbd>.

#### Bonus

Try holding combinations of <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>, and arrows for improved selection power.

Comment: Thanks, very useful! I mapped my "Clone Caret Above/Below" to CTRL + SHIFT + UP/DOWN, because with ALT as you suggested it's already for moving lines and I use it quite often.

Comment: Mac: ⌘ + ⌘ (Hold) + ↑ / ↓ became ⌥ + ⌥ (Hold) + ↑ / ↓ on Monterey (maybe even earlier?).

Answer (score 24):

For both Mac and Windows, just open the Context Menu and click on the "Column selection mode" to enable or disable the behaviour..

[image]

Comment: You are my saviour! thanks

Answer (score 21):

**On a MacOS you can use:**

Tap: `Control` + `Command` + `G` - Select all the same value

Tap: `Control` + `G` - Every tap combination select the new same value

Hold: `Option` + `Mouse Click` - Select multiline with a mouse

Hold: `Option` + `Shift` and Tap: `Mouse Click` - duplicate cursor for a each tap place

Answer (score 13):

Press `Shift` + `Alt` + `Insert` combination to edit in Column selection mode.

Comment: good point. i didnt know that . you can toggle between column selection and normal selection using that

Comment: Warning, press `Shift` + `Alt` + `Insert` again to exit edit mode :). In this case a cursor can move up-down in usual way, not over spaces.

Comment: @CoolMind Yes I accept your comments. But i would say if column selection mode is enabled that is the expected behavior.

Comment: @vgokul129, thanks. I wrote so because didn't know how to disable this behaviour.

Answer (score 12):

On a mac I like to do <kbd>⌥ (option)</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>mouse click</kbd> on multiple lines in Android Studio 3.1.3.

Answer (score 4):

Use the following:

`ALT` + `SHIFT`

Answer (score 1):

on Mac ,  `hold OPTION + SHIFT` then use the mouse to highlight what you want to select

Answer (score 0):

On Windows, you can try a plugin whose name is ConyEdit. It has a great column mode based on regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using android studio arctic fox and pressing Alt alone and then selecting code is working properly in windows.